# Como fazer o docker responder a um domínio que não existe no /etc/hosts?

Tags: docker, host, map

No meu arquivo hosts eu tenho somente o seguinte os seguintes domínios:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   abc.com
```

Quando vou rodar a imagem uso o seguinte comando: `docker run -p 80:80 -v /Users/userName/Documents/siteABC:/var/www/html my_image`. Consigo escrever na URL `abc.com` ou `localhost` e o site funciona usando o servidor do docker, como esperado.

Eu queria saber se existe alguma maneira de criar o host dinamicamente quando rodo a imagem do docker.

Exemplo gostaria de poder escrever na URL `abcphp56.com` sem eu ter que criar esse domínio no meu `/etc/hosts`.

Segundo esse [post](http://jasani.org/2014/11/19/docker-now-supports-adding-host-mappings/), se eu bem entendi, bastaria rodar a imagem com o seguinte comando: `docker run  -p 80:80  --add-host abcphp56.com:127.0.0.1 -v /Users/userName/Documents/siteABC:/var/www/html my_image` e eu teria o sistema responsíveis aos 3 domínios: **localhost**, **abc.com** e **abcphp56.com**, mas não está funcionando.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como poderia fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que você está tentando fazer não é possível sem que você crie algum tipo de script que faça pesquisas recorrentes no docker para criar a configuração do arquivo hosts do seu host.

Quando falamos de --add-host ou ou quando pensamos na resolução de nomes dentro do docker, estamos falando exclusivamente do docker, não do seu host. Independente de estar em um host windows ou linux, o docker não interfere no seu arquivo hosts do host.

Portanto uma solução para sua questão é fazer pooling no docker para buscar modificações (novos containers) e recriar o arquivo hosts (do host) com base nos containers existentes.

Outra solução é usar de um service discovery como etcd, consul, linkerd (os principais possuem DNS próprio), e adicionar uma entrada na sua configuração de rede do host para que usar esse DNS server como dns secundário no seu stack de rede do host. É preciso testar essa solução com calma, mas em tese funcionaria.

Comment: Então Luiz, essa foi uma requisição do programador manager aqui da empresa. Então normalmente os programadores acessam o sistema como abc.com. Esse container vai ser usado como padrão para todos os programadores, mas ele não quer que cada um dos programadores, precisem ter que ir no /etc/hosts para editar algum dns. Ele pediu para fazer algo do tipo, criar uma lista de dns dentro do container que vai responder quando o o usuário escrever uma dessas urls no browser do host. Assim a lista dos dns já vem da imagem.

Comment: Então pelo que entendi do seu post, não tem como escapar da edição do hosts do host, correto? Seja automática seja manual.

Comment: Dendro da sua empresa você tem um DNS, portanto fazendo no seu DNS está tudo resolvido. Acredito que seu programador não saiba o que está pedindo, talvez eu possa ajudá-lo: @luizcarlosfaria no telegram. Acho que no final das contas, ele está pedindo algo que poderia ser mais simples.

Answer (score 0):

Adicione também **--network="host"**.

**--add-host** é uma opção que pode ser usada com a rede em modo **host**.

Por padrão, a rede do container é criada em modo **bridge**.

**Observando que:**
em modo host você terá um melhor desempenho de rede, mas, em contrapartida este modo é considerado inseguro e deve ser usado somente nos casos em que performance é essencial (por exemplo, um Load Balancer em produção)

`docker run  -p 80:80 --network="host" --add-host abcphp56.com:127.0.0.1 -v /Users/userName/Documents/siteABC:/var/www/html my_image`

**Alternativa 2**

Você pode criar links entre os containers. Quando você cria links, você pode se referir à outro container por um Alias. Ao usar link, o arquivo /etc/hosts é alterado e atribui o alias ao ip do container.
Exemplo:
`docker run -d --name backend imagembackend`

`docker run -d --name container_hosts --link backend:www.google.com imagem ping www.google.com`

Dentro do container_hosts o arquivo /etc/hosts terá a entrada wwww.google.com apontando para o IP do backend.

Comment: Oi Senio, eu sou iniciante em Docker. Pelo que entendi da documentação o --add-host parece inserir DNS no /etc/hosts dentro do container. E como vejo o erro no browser o DNS não pode ser encontrado.

Comment: Adicionei uma alternativa 2

Comment: Observando que estas alternativas são para iniciar seu entendimento sobre Docker sem usar soluções mais completas como um Service Discovery, Escalabilidade, etc.